# My gpt2 code generates a few correct words and then goes into a loop of generating the same sequence again and again

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, huggingface-transformers, gpt-2

The following gpt2 code for sentence completion generates a few good sentences and then ends in a loop of repetitive sentences.

```
from transformers import GPT2LMHeadModel, GPT2Tokenizer                         
import torch                                                                    
                                                                                
# Load the pre-trained model and tokenizer                                      
model_name = 'gpt2'                                                             
model = GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained(model_name)                             
tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)                           
                                                                                
# Set the model to evaluation mode                                              
model.eval()                                                                    
#                                                                               
# Input sentence                                                                
input_sentence = "I want to go to the"                                          
                                                                                
for i in range(200):                                                            
                                                                                
    # Tokenize the input sentence                                               
    input_tokens = tokenizer.encode(input_sentence, return_tensors='pt')        
                                                                                
    # Generate predictions                                                      
    with torch.no_grad():                                                       
        outputs = model.generate(input_tokens, max_length=len(input_tokens) + 1, num_return_sequences=1)
                                                                                
    # Decode the generated output                                               
    generated_output = tokenizer.decode(outputs[0], skip_special_tokens=True)   
                                                                                
    print(generated_output)                                                     
                                                                                
    input_sentence = generated_output
```

Answer (score 0):

`model.generate` has an optional argument `repetition_penalty`.  If you set the value to a value greater than 1, it should help.  In your case, it could be

```
model.generate(input_tokens, 
               max_length=len(input_tokens) + 1, 
               num_return_sequences=1,
               repetition_penalty = 5.0) # needs to be float
```

You may be interested in [many other generation options](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.27.1/en/main_classes/text_generation#transformers.GenerationConfig) that are available.